# Merchant selling price for 20% Gain

Tags: percentages

Here is the problem,

> on selling an article for $76$ dollars merchant loses $4$ dollars, to gain $20$% profit he has to sell it for X dollars.The selling price of the article to gain $20$% is...?

I found it as $96$ but the answer says it as more than $96$,,am I correct ..?

Comment: Thank you guys...I found the printing mistake as 4% not 4$ so for me the answer was right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the item is worth $x$, then $76-x=-4\implies x=80$. A $20\%$ profit is then $80\cdot\frac{2}{10}=16$. So the selling price is $80+16=96$. So it seems you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the selling price based on the [trade margin](http://retail.about.com/od/glossary/g/margin.htm) has to be calculated. The formula is

$\text{margin(%)}=\frac{\text{selling price - cost}}{\text{selling price}}=\frac{\text{x - 80}}{x}=0.2$

Comment: @VellankiGaneshBabu Have you seen, that the result of this equation is not $96 ?

Comment: yes it is 95 if 4% loss (not 4$), I mean I have calculated it.

Comment: @VellankiGaneshBabu Did you used the formula, which I have posted ? The calculation and the result is different from yours and Joel Bosvelds. What have you calculated ?

Comment: I have used your formula for the calculation of profit margins(subsequent formulas), I meant nice timing in Bad context though...

Comment: @VellankiGaneshBabu But I have in both cases (4%,$4) different results. That is why I asked for a calculation.

Comment: for this..question, I have got 96 for 4 and 95 for 4%...and I have not used your formula for computing this question but for other question in book so your formula and the link gave me a way, to know about profit margin concept..

Comment: @VellankiGaneshBabu OK. I only wondered, because you have written, that the given answer is more than 96.